# Event handling - onClick - with Google Analytics with an <embed> tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using the embed tag to play sound clips to users on one of my pages. It looks something like:

```
<EMBED src='my_soundfile.wav' type='audio/wav' 
controls='smallconsole' autostart='false'  
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'my_soundfile.wav']);">
</EMBED>
```

When I check Google Analytics (after 24 hrs.), nothing is showing up. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think quicktime is capturing the click events, if you replace your

```
onclick="_gaq..."
```

with

```
onclick="alert('test');"
```

you will see that id doesn't work either.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Andre. I may have to create another question, but would you have any suggestions on how I can trigger this?

Comment: I can't see any possible solutions... if you put an absolute transparent div above it you could capture it's clicks, but then you would have to be able to trigger a click inside the quicktime in response... don't think it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Rather than waiting 24 hours to see if any analytics data has been tracked, it's a good idea to get familiar with some network tools so you can at least see if there's been a request for the analytics tracking pixel. Some tools are:

- [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) -- web debugging proxy. You can add filters to only see traffic to google-analytics.com
- In Chrome, Developer Tools is your friend -- the Network tab can show the __utm.gif request from google-analytics.com.
- Likewise, Firefox and the [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) Net tab.

Answer (score 0):

It took a little bit of research, but I figured out how to capture the DOM events you're looking for, using the [Quicktime JavaScript API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html).

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PUv4s/6/

Add the following attributes to the `embed` tag:

```
postdomevents="true" EnableJavaScript="true"
```

Then, you can capture the events by doing something like:

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("qt_play", function(e) {
    console.dir(e);
    alert("play triggered");
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', e.target.src]);
}, false);
```

Obviously, this doesn't cover IE (which uses `attachEvent`), but, it should work similarly.